# Financial Numerical recipes ( Bernt Arne Ødegaard 2007): output not matching example output

Tags: c++, syntax, output

I am going through the financial numerical recipes in c++ by  Bernt Arne Ødegaard 2007,
You can find the whole document here: http://finance.bi.no/~bernt/gcc_prog/recipes/recipes.pdf

The link is very useful for this question as I have copied the code from there and it is the output to console that is differing.

I have completed the examples in chapter 4 (page 36) and when I run the examples (using visual studio 2012) I do not get the same output as what is given in the example outputs. I have looked for syntactical errors and deviations and cannot find any. I also do not see no reason why the output should be different.

For bonds_price_dicrete I get a value of 0.

Here is the example financial_recipies.cpp file code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

double bonds_price_discrete(const vector<double>& times,
const vector<double>& cashflows,
const double& r) {

double p=0;
for (int i=0;i<times.size();i++) {
p += cashflows[i]/(pow((1+r),times[i]));
};
return p;
};
```

Main program:

```
vector<double> cflows; cflows.push_back(10); cflows.push_back(10); cflows.push_back(110);

vector<double> times; times.push_back(1); times.push_back(2); times.push_back(3);

double r=0.09;

cout << " bonds price = " << bonds price discrete(times, cflows, r) << endl;
```

Example output:

```
bonds price = 102.531
```

I thought it might have been a a int vs float problem but changing all the doubles to floats did not do anything. Here is my code for financial_recipes.cpp:

```
double BondsPriceDiscrete(const vector<double> & Times, const vector<double> & cFlow, const double & rates)
{
    double P = 0 ; 

for (int i = 0 ; i < Times.size() ; i++)
{
    P += cFlow[i]/(pow((1+rates),Times[i])) ; 
}; 

return 0 ; 
}
```

My function which is called in main()

```
const int BondsPriceDiscrete() 
{
vector <double> cflow ; cflow.push_back(10) ; cflow.push_back(10) ;   cflow.push_back(110) ; 
vector <double> Times ; Times.push_back(1) ; Times.push_back(2) ;   Times.push_back(3) ;

double rates = 0.09 ; 

cout << "Bond Price: " << BondsPriceDiscrete(Times,cflow,rates) << endl ; 

return 0 ; 
}
```

My file structure is just a header file and cpp file for financial_numerical_recipes, I have inclusion guards and #include cmath, vector, algorithm, iostream, string.h and stdafx.h in the header file and the header file in the cpp file which runs main. There are no other file attachments and the code runs fine its just the outputs that don't match...

Just to note I am going through them to practice examples of c++ usage in finance, not for any commercial or product usage. Also this is my first time posting a question on stack overflow so if I have left anything out do comment and I will alter it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

watch what you return from the function

```
double BondsPriceDiscrete(const vector<double> & Times, const vector<double> & cFlow, const double & rates)
{
    double P = 0 ; 

    for (int i = 0 ; i < Times.size() ; i++)
    {
        P += cFlow[i]/(pow((1+rates),Times[i])) ; 
    }; 

    // return 0 ; 
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, been staring at that code a while now don't know how I missed it!

Comment: @cade.camsis - I hate it when that happens!